# Understanding the input of PyTorch LSTM

Tags: pytorch, lstm

I'm trying to figure out how PyTorch LSTM takes input. I've read the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html), but I'd like someone more experienced to confirm or correct what I've gathered so far.

Initially, let's establish notation in accordance with the documentation.

1. N = Batch Size
2. L = Sequence Length
3. H-IN = input_size where input_size is defined as

> The number of expected features in the input x

where x is defined as the input at time *t* ****if** I've understood correctly**.

I'll provide 2 examples.

Example - 1:

Say I have 3 instances/sequences per batch so N = 3 and each instance/sequence  is represented as [X, Y] where X and Y are numbers so L = 2 and both X and Y correspond to the first and second timestep respectively.

Therefore the correct way to do it for 1 layer and a hidden state of 4 would be like this:

```
batch_tensor = torch.tensor([
    # The first sequence [1, 2] of length 2 where 1 is the first timestep and 2 is the second timestep
    [[1], [2]],

    # The second sequence [4, 5] of length 2 where 4 is the first timestep and 5 is the second timestep    
    [[4], [5]],  

    # The third sequence [7, 8] of length 2 where 7 is the first timestep and 8 is the second timestep    
    [[7], [8]]  
], dtype=torch.float32)

print(batch_tensor.shape)

# Outputs -> torch.Size([3, 2, 1])

# input_size should be 1 as each timestep has dimensionality of 1
lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=1, hidden_size=4, num_layers=1, batch_first=True)
```

Example - 2:

Thsi time I have 3 instances/sequences per batch so N = 3 and each instance/sequence  is represented as [X, Y] where X and Y are **vectors this time** so L = 2 and both X and Y correspond to the first and second timestep respectively.

Therefore the correct way to do it for 1 layer and a hidden state of 4 would be like this:

```
batch_tensor = torch.tensor([
    # The first sequence [[1, 1.5], [2, 2.5]] of length 2 where [1, 1.5] is the first timestep and [2, 2.5] is the second timestep
    [[1, 1.5], [2, 2.5]],

    # The second sequence [[4, 4.5], [5, 5.5]] of length 2 where [4, 4.5] is the first timestep and [5, 5.5] is the second timestep
    [[4, 4.5], [5, 5.5]],

    # The third sequence [[7, 7.5], [8, 8.5]] of length 2 where [7, 7.5] is the first timestep and [8, 8.5] is the second timestep
    [[7, 7.5], [8, 8.5]]
], dtype=torch.float32)

print(batch_tensor.shape)

# Outputs -> torch.Size([3, 2, 2])

# input_size should be 2 as each timestep has dimensionality of 2
lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=2, hidden_size=4, num_layers=1, batch_first=True)
```

Questions:

1. Are my examples correct?
2. In both examples after playing around to see if something would break, I decided to set the input_size to 2000 but it still worked and I wonder why that is.

Answer (score 0):

The `nn.LSTM` module takes in an input of size `(bs, sl, n)` or `(sl, bs, n)` depending on the `batch_first` parameter.

The LSTM input is expected to be a full sequence. This is in contrast to the `nn.LSTMCell` module which takes in a single timestep at a time.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

inputs = torch.tensor([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [7, 8, 0, 0]
])

d_embedding = 32
d_hidden = d_embedding*2

embedding = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=12, embedding_dim=d_embedding)
lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=d_embedding, hidden_size=d_hidden, num_layers=3, batch_first=True)

x_embedded = embedding(inputs)
(output, (hidden_state, cell_state)) = lstm(x_embedded)
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example without an Embedding layer as it makes things harder to understand and also comment on your code? I can't understand what you consider as a sequence here and what you consider as a timestep. In my examples both of these things are obvious.

Comment: I took a look at your comment again. If I understand correctly you represent each input as sequence of 4 timesteps with each timestep having 32 dimensions. From what I understand by exploring many more resources both your example and my examples are correct. But I still can't figure out why things work flawlessly even when I set the input_size to 2000 in your example.